# Flutter GoRouter nested routing not working

Tags: flutter

I cant get this work with GoRouter when I have nested routes. I get error. The nesting looks right for me, but I have no idea why it throws an error.

Here is some code snippets, hopefully i could get help go understand what i'm doing wrong

The error is pointing at the name parameter

````
@TypedGoRoute<SongListRoute>(
  path: "/songList",
  routes: <TypedRoute<RouteData>>[
    TypedGoRoute<SongDetailsRoute>(
      path: "songDetails/:songId",
      routes: <TypedRoute<RouteData>>[
        TypedGoRoute<SongDetailsEditRoute>(
          path: "songDetailsEdit",
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
class SongListRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const SongListRoute();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
      const SongListView();
}

class SongDetailsRoute extends GoRouteData {
  const SongDetailsRoute({
    required this.songId,
    required this.name,
  });

  final int songId;
  final String name;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) =>
      SongDetailsView(
        songId: huntingAreaId,
        name: name,
      );
}
```

```
SongDetailsRoute(songId: 100, name: "M.J Thriller").push(context);
```

```
flutter: Null check operator used on a null value
flutter:
#0      $SongDetailsRouteRouteExtension._fromState
```
````